# How To Install a Subversion 1.7.3 server on Bluehost

Tags: svn, installation, bluehost

I have a Bluehost account, and I want to install a personal Subversion server on it. I have come across a couple of tutorials, but they are for version 1.4.6, and certain issues in the build process seem to have changed, so I'm rather lost.

So, my question is this: how can I set up a personal Subversion server on Bluehost, for 1.7.3? (NOTE: I have SSH working, btw.)

I have no real experience with doing this before, so detailed advice/explanations would be nice.

Comment: I guess this should be asked on serverfault. Add the OS you are using (if Linux/Unix, which flavor).

Comment: [Heres one for 1.5](http://legobuff.com/2008/09/07/howto-install-subversion-on-bluehost/), the build process shouldnt be much different except for which arch you need to build for (32 or 64) and the respective `CFLAGS`. Please post more info about the server as J.N. suggested. Also voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: I placed another question: http://serverfault.com/questions/365906/how-to-install-a-subversion-1-7-3-server-on-bluehost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I settled for installing an older version of SVN. Numerous tutorials for that exist, I followed [this one](http://legobuff.com/2008/09/07/howto-install-subversion-on-bluehost/).

Answer (score -1):

Usually there are no rights for ordinary shared hosting users to perform such kind of operations. All you can do is ask Bluehost administrators to install subversion for you.

Comment: Not true. I have install capacity over ssh.